# Excel cannot read my SQL connection string

Tags: excel, vba

Previously I have an Excel program that uses macro to perform an SQL query within the Excel itself.

```
Public Sub QueryWorksheet(szSQL As String, rgStart As Range, wbWorkBook As String)
Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim szConnect As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.StatusBar = "Retrieving data ....."
'Set up the connection string to excel - thisworkbook
szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & wbWorkBook & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
'Run the query as adCmdText
rsData.Open szSQL, szConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'Check if data is returned
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    'if the recordset contains data put them on the worksheet
    rgStart.CopyFromRecordset rsData
Else
 '   MsgBox "There's no records that matches the query !!", vbCritical
End If
'Close connection
rsData.Close
'Clean up and get out
Set rsData = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
'an error occured in the SQL-statement
MsgBox "Your query could not be executed, the SQL-statement is incorrect."
Set rsData = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

On my old PC it worked fine. But now that I've changed to a new laptop I keep having problems with the macro. As it goes straight to error handler the moment it passes the line `rsData.Open szSQL, szConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText`.

I checked the References and made sure ActiveX Data Objects was selected. But still no dice.

What else am I possible missing here?

[image]

Comment: Are you using 64-bit or 32-bit Excel? The JET driver is 32-bit only. That said, you shouldn't use JET for reading Excel files (JET is for Access, but it supports Excel by indirectly using the Excel driver, so you're adding a pointless layer of indirection). Use the dedicated Excel ODBC driver instead: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-excel-odbc-driver/

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Goto ErrHandler` and run it.  What is the actual error message and on which line?

Comment: error occurs at line `rsData.Open szSQL, szConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText`. Runtime error 3706: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

Comment: @Dai I'm using 64-bit excel. But funny enough my colleague is also using 64 bit excel but she said she's having no problems with it at the moment. Whether or not its true I can say for sure...